# C sockets accept() failing when there are no connections in the queue

Tags: c, sockets, gcc

I am reading a book on sockets in c and am making a very simple server program. I copied the code verbatim. There is nothing trying to connect to this server program yet and have change the port multiple times to make sure.

The program is failing on the accept method on the first run of the loop. From what I read in the man pages, accept is supposed to block the caller until a connection is made, and not fail if there aren't connections in the queue like it is doing. Is there any reason accept would be returning a value less than 0? I will post the code up to where it fails:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

//Max number of outstanding connection requests
#define MAXPEDNING 5
#define NONE
#define BUFSIZE 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    in_port_t servPort;

    #ifdef CMDLINE
        if(argc != 2)
        {
            puts("Error! Usage is <Server Port>");
            return 0;
        }

        servPort = atoi(argv+1);
    #endif //CMDLINE

    #ifdef NONE
        servPort = 2549;
    #endif //NONE

    int servSock;
    if((servSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
    {
        puts("socket() failed");
        return 0;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in servAddr;

    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(servPort);

    printf("Port in network order: %d\nPort in host order:%d\n", servAddr.sin_port, ntohs(servAddr.sin_port));

    if((bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)))<0)
    {
        puts("bind failed");
        return 0;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in clntAddr;
        socklen_t clntAddrLen = sizeof(clntAddr);

        int clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr*) &clntAddr, &clntAddrLen);

        if(clntSock < 0)
        {
            puts("accept failed");
            return 0;
        }
```

It reaches the accept failed and quits. The only thing that is odd about my setup is that I am on a Debian VM (VirtualBox) and I am wondering if network operations are handled in a weird way. I shouldn't be even trying to accept anything because there are no connections.

Comment: When you get -1 from a system call you are supposed to examine the errno, which tells you what the problem is. Without that, debugging is just a guessing game, or a time-wasting Internet forum exercise. You certainly are not supposed to just print an arbitrary, errno-independent message and quit.

Comment: @EJP That makes sense. The book probably didn't include that because it is just an intro program. Will do that in the future though.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `listen()` in between `bind()` and `accept()`.

Comment: and before the loop starts :)